# How to enable Liked By column in modify view?

Tags: list-view, rating

Hello all i have a list where i have enabled ratings as a form of likes , but when i am modifying view the **liked by** column is not coming up so that i can tick/untick . Is there something i need to enable? any feature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Ratings feature is enabled and “Likes” is the selected rating option, you cannot select/deselect **Liked by** in the view settings.  It appears grayed out and is tied to the **Number of Likes** column.  When **Number of Likes** is selected to display in a view, to see the **Liked by** data, users hover their mouse over the smiley face in the **Number of Likes** column and a list of users who liked the item will dynamically appear.

Comment: Yes this feature is there but isnt there a way to activate the liked by thing?

Comment: So, you have a list with ratings enabled, using likes, and you have a view with the column "Number of Likes" selected and displayed.  Is that right?  To see the "Liked by" information, at least one user needs to "like" an item.  Once an item has been liked, a user can then hover their mouse over the smiley face and a listing of the users who liked the item will appear.

Comment: Yes correct that is there by default, but is there a way to activate liked by columns? Why is it disabled?

Comment: Liked by details are tied to the Number of Likes column.  As long as the Number of Likes displays and at least one person has liked an item, the Liked by information will appear in a mouseover. I cannot speak on the design decision.